# package Homestead box wrong: The Vagrant virtual environment you are trying to package must be powered off

Tags: vagrant, homestead

when i package Homestead-box:

```
➜  Homestead git:(master) vagrant halt
➜  Homestead git:(master) vagrant package --output h-0417.box
The Vagrant virtual environment you are trying to package must be powered off.
➜  Homestead git:(master) vagrant box list
coreos-alpha      (virtualbox, 509.1.0)
coreos-alpha      (virtualbox, 522.0.0)
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 0.4.2)
➜  Homestead git:(master) vagrant package --output h-0417.box --base laravel/homestead.box
==> laravel/homestead.box: VM not created. Moving on...
➜  Homestead git:(master) pwd
/Users/qk/Homestead
➜  Homestead git:(master) vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.8.1
```

here is my reference:

[how-to-create-a-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-one](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-a-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-one)

[How-to-Create-a-CentOS-Vagrant-Base-Box](https://github.com/okfn/ckan-barnet/wiki/How-to-Create-a-CentOS-Vagrant-Base-Box)

and i continue to uninstall some parallel plugin and restart osx it meets the same error :

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-parallels

➜  Homestead git:(master) vagrant package --output h-0418.box
The Vagrant virtual environment you are trying to package must be powered off.
➜  Homestead git:(master) pwd
/Users/qk/Homestead
➜  Homestead git:(master) ls
LICENSE.txt   composer.json homestead     init.sh       scripts
Vagrantfile   composer.lock init.bat      readme.md     src
```

is there some logs or how to checkout some other plugin is installed to cause this error.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, but tried bringing the Vagrant box up, then halting it, and then the package command worked.